# Plotly px.bar not stacking with barmode='stack'

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create a single-column bar chart with the desired result looking something like this
[image]

I figured the barmode = 'stack' would do the trick but the bars are not stacking

[image]

```
lang    count   percentage
Undetermined    1202    37.56
English (default)   806 25.19
Arabic  529 16.53
French  524 16.38 
German  32  1.00


import plotly.express as px
fig_lang=px.bar(df_lang,
            y='lang',
            x='percentage',
            color='lang',
            color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.T10,
            barmode='stack', 
            orientation = 'h',
     text=df_lang['percentage'].apply(lambda x: '{0:1.2f}%'.format(x)))
fig_lang.show()
```

Any pointers to why or how to accomplish this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

- effectively you want to plot all the bars against same **x** value.  Have done this by setting it as a constant in data frame
- then it's simple case of using **color** and **y**

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df_lang = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """lang    count   percentage
Undetermined    1202    37.56
English_(default)   806 25.19
Arabic  529 16.53
French  524 16.38 
German  32  1.00"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
)

px.bar(df_lang.assign(bar=1), color="lang", x="bar", y="percentage").update_layout(
    xaxis_visible=False, autosize=False, width=300
)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense, thank you!