# plotly: bar stacking graph

Tags: python, plot, graph, plotly

I have a Dataframe with data as follows:

```
data={'A': {'2020_01': 3, '2020_02': 3, '2020_03': 1, '2020_04': 3, '2020_05': 1},
 'B': {'2020_01': 0, '2020_02': 0, '2020_03': 3, '2020_04': 0, '2020_05': 2},
 'other': {'2020_01': 0,
  '2020_02': 0,
  '2020_03': 3,
  '2020_04': 0,
  '2020_05': 2},
 'total': {'2020_01': 3,
  '2020_02': 3,
  '2020_03': 7,
  '2020_04': 3,
  '2020_05': 5}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to represent with ploty in X the dates and in y stacked values of A, B, other

for one single bar I can do:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y='A', text_auto=True,
             labels={'A':'bananas'}, height=400)
fig.show()
```

How to I have to proceed?
I checked a bunch of documentation at no avail:
https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-express-bar-ignores-barmode-group/31511
https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/
[Plotly px.bar not stacking with barmode='stack'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912693/plotly-px-bar-not-stacking-with-barmode-stack)
...
Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you should do the following:

1. Reset the index and use it as column.
2. Use `melt` function to convert the dataframe in the appropriate form.
3. Use `barmode="stack"` to plot the stacked bars.

   ```
   import plotly.express as px
   import pandas as pd

   df.reset_index(inplace=True)
   df = df.iloc[:,:-1].melt(id_vars='index', var_name='categories', value_name='count')
   fig = px.histogram(df, x="index", y="count", text_auto=True, color="categories", barmode="stack",
        labels={'A':'bananas'}, height=400)
   fig.show()
   ```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. this is pretty close. IN the question I mentioned two things, only A,B, other values and Stacked. i.e. one of top of each other. Like only three colors, for instance in 2020_03 there would be one vertical bar with 1(blue)3(red)3(green)

Comment: I added a pic in the question